# MongoDB does not search for documents

Tags: node.js, mongodb

but I cant find any items after ID,

Calendar.model inside is doc:

```
/* 1 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5a3425b58399c6c26cf1c848"),
    "doctorID" : ObjectId("5a31392cc99fe923c0810096"),
    "doctor" : "Bartłomiej Flis",
    "calendar" : []
}
```

And in nodeJS API  I am trying to find the doc using function:

router.get('/list-of-dates', (req, res)=> {

```
Calendar.find({ doctorID : req.query.doctorID})
.then((Calendar)=>{
    console.log(Calendar)
    res.send(Calendar)
})
.catch((err)=>{
    console.log(err)
})
```

});

the value of req.query.doctorID is string -> 5a31392cc99fe923c0810096

Anyone can tell me why this function can't find any item? I think it is the fault that in the database variable doctorID is as ObjectId and in the API req.query.doctorID is a string, how to improve it in the API to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, import in the beginning of the file the following:

```
const ObjectID = require('mongodb').ObjectId;
```

Then, change your search query to (i.e. wrap it into the *ObjectId()* function)

```
{ doctorID: ObjectId( req.query.doctorID ) }
```

**What is the difference?** MongoDB stores keys in `ObjectId` type, whereas you are trying to find something with type `String`. You were correct. That's why you do not get anything.

Let me know if that helps.

Comment: Ok work, but in callback I get empty array, maybe u know why I didn't find this doc?

Comment: Probably, your doc is empty? Also, instead of `(Calendar) => ...` simply put `(calendars) => ...`, because capital letter words are used for types (`Boolean`, `String`, etc.)

Comment: Can u look here? I think is something with collection because, I change find for save and when I am trying to do that is error that Calendar is not a constructor can u look here please? https://gist.github.com/anonymous/7ae2796a51c2a28f88469415054f7a31 and thanks for information about capital lettter

Comment: 1. Change the type of `doctorID` from *String* to *ObjectID* in your schema 2. Add the following to beginning of your file (after `var mongoose...`)  `var ObjectID = mongoose.Types.ObjectId;`

Comment: Another problem is here `function (Calendars)`. Do not use capital letter params/args, etc. they are only for types like `String`, etc. !! Instead, change it to `function (calendars)` or other, but make sure it is lower-case.

Comment: Hey it didnt help :/ 
look changes : https://gist.github.com/Turqus/32d2a7a3e17a309013063375aa3b10c6

Comment: @AnetaJabłońska then try instead of this `var Calendar = new Calendar(newVisit);` the following `var Calendar = new CalendarSchema(newVisit);`

Comment: Hey thanks for help, I found the problem, I just change var Calendar = new Calendar(newVisit); on var calendar = new Calendar(newVisit); and later I use lower case too in calendar.save, later I tried make calendar.find but was error that dont exissts this variable, so I change for Calendar.find and finally I find it, I dont understand why when I should use capital letter or lower letter

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/161337/discussion-between-oneturkmen-and-aneta-jablonska).